# Java convert date format

Tags: java, date-format

I got format like this

> 25 Jul 2015 07:32:16

and I want it like this

> 2015-07-25 07:32:16

How can I do it using java?

Comment: Add your code. How do you get your date from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use two [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)s - one to parse the string into a `Date` instance and the other to format it to your desired output.

```
String input = "25 Jul 2015 07:32:16";
DateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date date = parser.parse(input);
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String output = formatter.format(date);
```

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to have two [date formatters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), one to parse your date in the source format and another to format it in the target format. It goes like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat fromFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date date = fromFmt.parse("25 Jul 2015 07:32:16");;

SimpleDateFormat toFmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(toFmt.format(date));
```

You can find an executable version of this code [shared here](http://goo.gl/ldyWVv)

Answer (score 1):

Look at SimpleDateFormat

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

It can be used to parse a string to a date

[Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

And then used to take that date and reparse it as a different formatted string

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/text/java-simpledateformat-example/

something like this

```
mydate = "25 Jul 2015 07:32:16"

DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d MM yyyy H:m:s")
Date date = format.parse(mydate)

DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-m-d H:m:s")

String finalOutput = outputFormat.format(date)
```