# Convert date format in below format

Tags: java, date

Hi i have a date varilable here date is in following formate:

```
Fri Nov 06 23:59:59 IST 2015
```

Now i want to convert thi date in below format

```
2015-11-06 23:59:59
```

I am using this but not working:

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat(fromDate);
                Date currentdate;
                currentdate=sdf.parse(fromDate);
                System.out.println("TestDATE"+currentdate);
```

How can I convert?

Comment: _In which way_ is it not working? Please specify and also add input and output you get. Btw, you should pass a format string to the `SimpleDateFormat` constructor, not the date itself.

Comment: Is the input a date or a string? A date type has no format. Plase show a minimal runable example

Comment: maybe it's a duplicate Question please check those answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624828/java-convert-date-format

And

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)?

Your `fromPattern` needs to be: `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy` and `toPattern` - `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`.

Answer (score 0):

Date is a container for the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch ( 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970).

It has no concept of format.

please check those answer:
[Java convert date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624828/java-convert-date-format)

And

[Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)