# How I can get date object in format yyyy-MM-dd after date parsing

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-format, date

I have string date 2020-07-05 22:44:59 in string format, I parse it with SimpleDateFormat with
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a z" date pattern but it gives me date like Sun Jul 05 22:44:59 IST 2020.
So how I can get date in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a z" format in date object.

Input : 2020-07-05 22:44:59
Output : 2020-07-05 22:44:59

I want output int the same format like input.

Thanks for Helping me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java convert date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624828/java-convert-date-format)

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "2020-07-05 22:44:59";
DateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = parser.parse(input);
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String output = formatter.format(date);
```